# .HTACCESS Mod Rewrite with NO suffix?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get the following Mod Rewrite to work with no trailing slash as a suffix or file name.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /example1/example2/index.php?brand=

$1&video=$2 [L]
```

The above works however if I remove the trailing slash from /$ it wont work.

So just to recap:

> www.example.co.uk/example/example2/index.php?brand=x&video=y

rewrites to

> www.example.co.uk/test/brand/video/

but I can't get it working for

> www.example.co.uk/test/brand/video

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the regular expression from `^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$` to `^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$`